# Can you synchronize docker containers on different machines using git?

Tags: mysql, git, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on small project at uni, and I wonder if is it possible to synchronize two docker containers using git/github. We are working in pairs on the database, and each of us has a database running on docker (both with same settings, started by same docker-compose file). 
We need to populate both databases with same data, and would be easier if we can work separetly and just sync our db's using git or something like that. I know that creating some sql scripts with data would be better/easier but I'm just curious.
I thought about copying volume file to git, and creating some simple script that pull volume from repo and copy it to volume of existing DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Creating database dumps

Most of the normal tools will work, although their usage might be a little convoluted in some cases to ensure they have access to the mysqld server. A simple way to ensure this is to use docker exec and run the tool from the same container, similar to the following:

$ docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql

Restoring data from dump files

For restoring data. You can use docker exec command with -i flag, similar to the following:

$ docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' < /some/path/on/your/host/all-data

@source: dockerhub
```

Consider this when working with database data. You can integrate git with the dumps so you can work on branches and pull or push the changes and then just populate the database.